# Is there any way to compare two timestamps in Python SDK for Firestore database in Firebase?

Tags: python, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

```py
def on_snapshot(col_snapshot, changes, read_time):
    for change in changes:
        if change.type.name == 'ADDED' or change.type.name == 'MODIFIED':
            doc_ref = db.collection('Records').document(change.document.id)
            doc_data = doc_ref.get().to_dict()
            
            print("\n")
            if change.type.name == 'ADDED':
                print(f"New document: {change.document.id}")
            else:
                print(f"Modified document: {change.document.id}")
                print("Updated Document Data:", doc_data)
        elif change.type.name == 'REMOVED':
            print("\n")
            print(f"Removed document: {change.document.id}")

       collection_ref = db.collection('Records')
       start_timestamp = firestore.SERVER_TIMESTAMP

       while True:
          query = collection_ref.where(filter=FieldFilter('timestamp', '>', 
                  start_timestamp))
          query_watch = query.on_snapshot(on_snapshot)
    
          try:
             input("Press Enter to stop the listener...\n")
          except KeyboardInterrupt:
             query_watch.unsubscribe()
             break
```

I have coded a listener program to print changes in the Firestore database on the console. The code works fine but whenever I run the code, the already existing documents in Firestore are also printed on the console. I don't want the existing documents to be printed, I just want the newly added documents to be printed on the console(i.e the documents added, updated or removed after I run the listener program). So, I tried to use timestamp to compare the timestamp field of each document before it is printed on the console. But, the query is not working. Is there any way to fix this code?